# What's up with Gedit's HTML highlighting?

Tags: gedit, html, syntax-highlighting

I've been learning some HTML code recently, and something weird is up with Gedit's highlighting. Whenever I try to use the `<h3>` tag, Gedit immediately cancels all the highlighting and the text becomes plain white. If I leave and come back, the problem persists. The only way to get the highlighting back is to restore and earlier version of the file by not saving or to start all over again. Does anyone know what's going on?

Extra details:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Gedit Version: 3.36.2

Gedit Color Scheme: Cobalt

Screenshots:

Pre-pressing enter (look at the  tag)

[image: Pre-pressing enter (look at the tag]

Post-pressing enter

[image: Post-pressing enter (look at the tag)]

Comment: Would you mind sharing some screenshots? I'm having Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the same GEdit version as you have.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and Gedit 3.38.0 and I can confirm this is an issue for me too. If I load up a .html file say the very basic example shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp then syntax highlighting is correct. As soon as I add another h tag I get as far as typing `<h2>` and all text goes white. Then the only way to get highlighting back is seemingly to close and re-open gedit.

Comment: @JijoJoseph I have put in some screenshots.

Comment: @codlord That sounds about right for me, too. Hopefully there's a way to fix this.

Comment: It's an issue. You may log it here [gedit issues](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues). I'd suggest using [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) for HTML editing

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour as well. I experience this almost every day. @codlord are right, it often happen with tiny HTML scripts, when you are opening a new header tag, but I have interestingly never seen it on larger docs, >1k.